# Funny Characters in Plain Text email when sending using PHPMailer

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpmailer

I have a strange problem. I read text from a text file replace all values using str_replace with the relevant values and then send the email via PHPMailer in plain text to the recipient.

Now my problem is whenever the recipient gets my mails he sees characters like '0D'

```
1. DOMAIN NAME and ACTION=0D
=0D
    Give the name of the subdomain.  This is the name that will be=0D
    used in tables and lists associating the domain with the name=0D
    server and IP addresses.  The .co.za domain names that are=0D
    delegated by UniForum S.A. are at the third level, for example:=0D
    thisnetwork.co.za.  Domain names in the CO.ZA zone are limited=0D
    to 30 characters.=0D
    The Action field specifies whether this is a 'N'ew application, an=0D
    'U'pdate or a 'D'eletion.=0D
```

This is my PHPMailer code where I try and set the encoding as well and this does not work either

```
$mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like "[quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)" content-transfer-encoding.

You can set the transfer-encoding as follows:

```
$mailer->Encoding = "8bit";
```

There should be a list of supported encodings in the manual of PHPMailer.

Comment: Thx for the guidance 8bit did not work, but 7bit did the trick

Comment: Have you tried sending non-ASCII characters using 7bit encoding? I think that might break.

Comment: This I removed $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; and the changed the encoding to 7bit and then all worked, or am I missig something. Also tested the text and that's ASCII